# Is the name Kabeer mentioned in the Vedas ? Is Kabeer Das a god According to the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda

I was challenged by a person who told me that kabeer das is a god. According to the Vedas and that he contributed a few Vedic lines but I don't know much about the Vedas, but have a huge respect for it.
Please clarify.
 [image]

Comment: Nope. Those mantras have altogether different meanings. Read Vedas with Sanskrit and English translations from http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/vedas

Comment: The person who challenged you might not aware of Vedas or Sanskrit...he might hv studied Gyan Ganga (a book of Kabir panthis)..in this book verses are taken from Vedas but are mistranslated...I hv checked few years back and found that their claim is not true...

Comment: I welcome answers from everyone.

Comment: absolutely no, kabir is not the god.

Comment: My goodness, No, not at all. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short and definite answer is **NO**. There is not a single word about kabir in vedas.

---

**TL;DR**

That person must be a kabir panthi ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabir_panth ), most probably a follower of arrested preacher Rampal.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rampal#Initiation_into_Kabir_panth

---

All those above references are false interpretations.
For example: Rigveda mandal 10 Hymn 10 mantra 3(as in above list) is
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Rig_Veda/Mandala_10/Hymn_90

> 3. So mighty is his greatness; yea, greater than this is Purusa.
>       All creatures are one-fourth of him, three-fourths eternal life in heaven.

The original sanskrit mantra is available in pdf file http://www.sanskritweb.net/rigveda/rv10-006.pdf

There is no mentions of kabir there.

What trick Rampal does is that he will (intentionally) mis-interpret "greatness"/mighty/Purusa literal words in above like mantras as talking about "kabir" word (The literal meaning of the arabic word 'Kabir' is: "Magnificent; great; big"), and then he will now say that this mantra mentions/points to "kabir" named individual.
This is the same trick, which is used by zakir naik too.

In the same way, none of the mantra referenced above contains kabir word in any form. Word "kabir" from Arabic language can in any case how come be in vedic ancient sanskrit language.